# PHP XML for Google Maps InfoWindow

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, google-maps-api-3

What I'm trying to do is to get the following from my Google maps. I'm aware with JavaScript that it's client side and not server side like PHP so it is loaded before the JS is even ran. The problem is if I were to call the column post_id strictly through PHP -> XML -> JS into the PHP it wouldn't load a link. Is there a way to do this with strictly just PHP and have it pull the locations post_id from the markers table for each of the location markers on the map? I've also read that it is possible with AJAX but I don't have alot of knowledge about AJAX.

```
boxText.innerHTML = "<div class='mapname'>" + '<a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $post_id ); ?>">' + name + '</a>' + "</div><i>" + listtype + "</i> <br/>" + address + "<br/>" + phone;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a complete PHP-Javascript AJAX example. Just save the file with the name 
"myServerScript.php" and point your browser to it. PHP prints javascript which calls the same PHP script via AJAX, PHP responds and javascript processes the response.

Make sure your PHP installation is configured to accept the short delimiters `<?...?>`

```
<?

if(isset($_GET['msg'])){
    print "alert('AJAX response from PHP - Javascript said:". $_GET['msg']."')";
}
else{
    print <<<qq
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<title>AJAX Example: (by Marcelo)</title>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>


<script>
// Sorry, I can't be bothered typing "google.maps." every time. ;-)
var G = google.maps;

var zoom = 4;
var centerPoint = new G.LatLng(40.178873, -96.767578);
var container;
var map;


function ajaxLoad(url,callback,plain) {
    var http_request = false;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, ...
        http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        if (http_request.overrideMimeType && plain) {
            http_request.overrideMimeType('text/plain');
        }
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
        try {
            http_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                http_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {}
        }
    }
    if (!http_request) {
        alert('Giving up :( Cannot create an XMLHTTP instance');
        return false;
    }
    http_request.onreadystatechange =  function() {
        if (http_request.readyState == 4) {
            if (http_request.status == 200) {
                eval(callback(http_request));
            }
            else {
                alert('Request Failed: ' + http_request.status);
            }
        }
    };
    http_request.open('GET', url, true);
    http_request.send(null);
}
var url = "myServerScript.php?msg=hello from javascrpt";
ajaxLoad(url, parseResults, true);


function parseResults(req){
    var text = req.responseText;
    eval(text);
}

function load() {
    container = document.getElementById('mapDiv');

    var myOptions = {
        zoom: zoom,
        center: centerPoint,
        mapTypeId: G.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        rotateControl: true,
        keyboardShortcuts:false
    }
    map = new G.Map(container, myOptions);
 google.maps.event.addListener(map,'click',function(mev){
var url = "myServerScript.php?msg="+mev.latLng;
ajaxLoad(url, parseResults, true);    
  });
}

window.onload = load;

</script>
</head>
<body>
Hello from PHP.
<h2>Click on the map to send the lat/lon to PHP</h2>
<div id="mapDiv" style="width: 800px; height: 450px;"></div>
</body>
</html>

qq;

}


?>
```

[**Live version here**](http://maps.forum.nu/myServerScript.php)

Comment: Sorry on the delay I'm still working on using this and I will let you know!