# Google map with a lot of markers, choice on data structure

Tags: json, google-maps

The latitude and longitude in mysql database. I wonder what is the proper way to output those data to the webpage. If the data are output by PHP and store in javascript like

var locations = [
  ['218 S. Wabash Building (TE)', '218 S Wabash Ave
 Chicago, IL 60604', 41.8789520, -87.6261270, 0],
  ['33 E. Congress Building (C)', '33 E Congress
 Chicago, IL', 41.87560160,  -87.62651219999999, 0]
......

then many information stored there would be redundant, as only the data pertaining to the present view of the map is useful. Of course, when user zooms out or drag to another view, I would like to have the relevant markers.

Have anyone had the experience developing similar apps? What would be the most efficient solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use Ajax. When the viewport changes, load the relevant markers from your database according to the current lantitude/longtitude/viewport.

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar with ajax. But I guess I can only load the data from database through php? Is it possible to use ajax to execute php?

Comment: Yes, you can call your PHP script with the lat/long paramters, make a database request and send the data from your database back to your script. Have a look at jQuery, which provides a method called .ajax() and other Ajax tutorials in general.

Comment: @StCee: See my reply to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12151520/php-xml-for-google-maps-infowindow/12153481#12153481 it's a complete PHP-Javascript AJAX example.

Comment: @Marcelo: I jsut have a look of the demo and it is great! It would be a good starting point. But I have to do more than echo-ing some message as I have to fetch data through database. BTW if you have the jquery version of your script I would love to see, as I have to load jquery on my page in any case. ;)

Comment: @StCee:  in the PHP section, where I echo the message, you can do any processing you want, like query your database, etc.. Sorry but I don't use jQuery or any plugins. Just plain old notepad here. ;-)

Comment: A good (albeit old) reference is the ["Part 11 The AJAX Philosophy"](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/basic11.htm) page from Mike Williams' v2 tutorial.  The same _concepts_ apply to v3, but won't work directly (and you should use v3 for any new development, as v2 was deprecated May 19, 2010).